Turn off ANSI colors in console logs
How can I turn off ANSI colors from RabbitMQ console logs?
I have a RabbitMQ instance that logs to console in order to catch log messages elsewhere (on GCP logs for example).
The problem is that, all log messages are prefixed with ANSI color codes, which cause the logs to be interpreted as INFO always.
For example, on errors, RabbitMQ logs with [38;5;160m prefix, which corresponds for the red color. See screenshots.
Here is my rabbitmq.conf
log.console = true
log.console.level = error
log.file = false



CLI Tools Show ANSI Character Sequences ?

In most production environments, you would want to analyse your logs. This becomes easier when the logs are formatted in a structured way. In RabbitMQ it is possible to format logs in JSON, which will also solve your ANSI colouring problem:
log.file.formatter = json
log.console.formatter = json
log.syslog.formatter = json 


Thanks. It worked.
Besides, log analysis is important, so two birds with one stone.
